# Exercise on calculating and plotting cumulated empirical distribution

Tags: python, statistics, montecarlo, mcmc

I was trying to finish an exercise in Jonh Stachurski's book (a textbook devoted to teach economists how to use Python). One of these is about how to calculate and plot cumulated empirical distribution. They provide a class called `ecdf` to calculate empirical distribution function

```
# Filename: ecdf.py
# Author: John Stachurski
# Date: December 2008
# Corresponds to: Listing 6.3

class ECDF:

    def __init__(self, observations):
        self.observations = observations

    def __call__(self, x):
        counter = 0.0
        for obs in self.observations:
            if obs <= x:
                counter += 1
        return counter / len(self.observations)
```

And the excercise reads

```
【Exercise 6.1.12】 Add a method to the ECDF class that uses Matplotlib to plot the em-
pirical distribution over a speciﬁed interval. Replicate the four graphs in ﬁgure 6.3
(modulo randomness).
```

the figure is need to be replicated is 
[image]

and an illusion of algorithm

[image]

The following is my initial attempt

```
from ecdf import ECDF
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from srs import SRS
from math import sqrt
from random import lognormvariate

# =========================
# parameters and arguments
# =========================
alpha, sigma2, s, delta = 0.3, 0.2, 0.5, 0.1
# numbers of draws
n = 1000
# length of each markov chain
t = 20
num_simu = [4,25,100,5000]

# Define F(k, z) = s k^alpha z + (1 - delta) k
F = lambda k, z: s * (k**alpha) * z + (1 - delta) * k 
lognorm = lambda: lognormvariate(0, sqrt(sigma2)) 


# =====================
#  create empirical distribution
# =====================

# different draw numbers
k = np.linspace(0,25,500)
for n in num_simu:
  for x in range(n):
    # list used to store capital stock (kt) in the last periods (t=20)
    kt = []  
    solow_srs = SRS(F=F, phi=lognorm, X=1.0)
    px = solow_srs.sample_path(t)
    kt.append(px[-1]) 
    # generate the empirical distribution function 
    F = ECDF(kt)
    prob_kt_n =   [F(i) for i in k]  # need to determine range
                                     # n refers to the n-th draw
# ==================================
# use for-loop to create subplots 
# ==================================   
#k = np.linspace(0,25,500)
#num_rows,num_cols = 2,2
```

The difficulties to me are 1) How can I store list/array of empirical distribution results for different draw numbers in the given graph. 2) How to create subplots using a for-loop. I also encountered some other tiny errors.
Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

About (1), my advice is to create a dictionary (i.e. something like `d = {}` and then `d[n] = ECDF(data)` for each number `n` of observations).

Dunno about (2).